# runhaskell Setup install Setup error

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal

I am trying to install packages from haskell's Hackage using Cabal.

In particular, I am trying to download the gloss package:

```
cabal install gloss
```

Comes up with this error:

```
binary-0.7.1.0 failed during the building phase. 
The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
bmp-1.2.5.2 depends on binary-0.7.1.0 which failed to install.
gloss-1.8.1.1 depends on binary-0.7.1.0 which failed to install.
```

I also tried binary-0.6.0.0. Because cabal install is not working, I am trying:

```
runhaskell Setup configure
runhaskell Setup build
runhaskell Setup install
```

...in the directory of the package, and I get the same error for every package:

```
Setup: Error: Could not find module: Data.Binary with any suffix: ["hi"] in 
the search path: ["dist/build"]
```

I am also having trouble installing the newest version of Cabal.

- cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
- using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
- The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
- Mac OSX 10.8 on MacBook Pro Retina

Comment: What package are you trying to install?  Have you tried just doing `cabal install package-name`?

Comment: The correct way to do it is to type `cabal install binary`.  You don't have to download the package to do this as `cabal` will auto-download it for you.

Comment: I updated my question. I was using cabal install in the first place.

Comment: The binary package fails to install on latest versions of osx because osx uses clang instead of gcc, and 'gcc' is usually just a symlink to clang. gcc is used in the pre-processor stage (haskell supports c-like macros) but clang does not support all the features for the pre-processor stage that gcc supports. 

To know if this is your problem, type 'gcc' in the terminal. If it says 'clang' somewhere, then this is the issue.

The solution is to get gcc, and replace the symlink to gcc with real gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary package fails to install on latest versions of osx because osx uses clang instead of gcc, and 'gcc' is usually just a symlink to clang. gcc is used in the pre-processor stage (haskell supports c-like macros) but clang does not support all the features for the pre-processor stage that gcc supports.

To know if this is your problem, type 'gcc' in the terminal. If it says 'clang' somewhere, then this is the issue.

The solution is to get gcc, and replace the symlink to gcc with real gcc. Using 'runhaskell' will still have the same issue. For the most part, you should never try to install packages without cabal, it is by far the easiest way.

Comment: I have installed gcc-4.8.2, but am still getting the error. How do I set the symlink to real gcc instead of clang? It still says 'clang' when I try gcc in Terminal (after a reset).

I am still getting the same error with cabal install gloss.

Comment: Delete usr/bin/gcc (which is just a symlink to clang) and create a symlink from gcc-4.8.2 (wherever you have installed it) to usr/bin/gcc. You can also configure ghc to look in a custom directory when it needs to invoke gcc, but this way is easier in my opinion.

Comment: Just a note for other OS X users: on my system /usr/bin/gcc did not show as a symlink, but it was clang rather than plain old gcc. I also had /usr/bin/clang, which I guess was a duplicate. I just renamed the clang version 'gcc-clang' in case I wanted it back later, and created a new symlink named 'gcc' that pointed to my gcc-4.7 install from homebrew. Snap and other cabal packages install fine now.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer.

If you have downloaded package `binary-0.7.1.0`, you can untar it first, and go into that folder, and run

```
cabal configure
cabal build
cabal install
```

There must be more `error message`, such as line number, but I didn't see it.